# Regex to match tags like <A>, <BB>, <CCC> but not <ABC>

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match tags that looks like `<A>`, `<BB>`, `<CCC>`, but not `<ABC>`, `<aaa>`, `<>`. so the tag must consist of the same uppercase letter, repeated. I've tried `<[A-Z]+>`, but that doesn't work. of course I can write something like `<(A+|B+|C+|...)>` and so on, but I wonder if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like this ([see this on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/Ys6CUah1k0)):

```
<([A-Z])\1*>
```

This uses capturing group and backreference. Basically:

- You use `(pattern)` to "capture" a match
- You can then use `\n` in your pattern, where `n` is the group number, to "refer back" to what that group matched

So in this case:

- Group 1 captures `([A-Z])`, an uppercase letter immediately following `<`
- Then we see if we can match `\1*`, i.e. zero or more of *that same letter*

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Grouping and Backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: @John: indeed, why not start with "what is regular expression".