# Matching a^n A^n with regular expression

Tags: regex

We're learning about the difference between regular languages and regex, and the teacher explained that the language

```
a^n b^n
```

is not regular, but she said that most regex flavors can match

```
a^n A^n
```

and she gave this problem for our extra credit homework problem. We've been struggling for a couple of days now, and could really use some guidance.

Comment: @kch the question is how do you match strings of that language with a regex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The teacher gave a *HUGE* hint by limiting the alphabet to `{a, A}`. The key to solving this problem is realizing that in case-insensitive mode, `a` matches `A` and vice versa. The other component of the problem is matching on backreference.

This pattern will match `a{n}A{n}` for some `n` ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/75OZuFJxl3)):

```
^(?=(a*)A*$)\1(?i)\1$
```

---

#### How it works

The pattern works as follows:

- `^(?=(a*)A*$)` - Anchored at the beginning of the string, we use positive lookahead to see if we can match `(a*)A*` until the end of the string

  - If we can succesfully make this assertion, then `\1` captures the sequence of `a{n}`
  - If the assertion fails, then there's no way the string can be `a{n}A{n}`, since it's not even `a*A*`
- We then match `\1(?i)\1$`, that is, the `a{n}` captured by `\1`, then *in case-insensitive mode* `(?i)`, we match `a{n}` again until the end of the string
- Thus, since:

  - The string is `a*A*`
  - `\1` is `a{n}`
  - `\1(?i)\1` can only be `a{n}A{n}`

#### Related questions

- [Case sensitive and insensitive in the same pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117159/case-sensitive-and-insensitive-in-the-same-pattern/)
- [How does the regular expression ‘(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)’ work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work/)

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [Grouping and backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) (esp. *Turning Modes On and Off for Only Part of The Regular Expression*)

#### See also

- [Why is {a^nb^n | n >= 0} not regular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309752/why-is-anbn-n-0-not-regular)
- [Wikipedia/Regular expression: Patterns for non-regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages)

Comment: For someone just learning the language theory, this little blurb is worth reading after this answer : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages

Comment: +1, Nice solution.  But one thing that confused me, how did you infer that 'a^n' means 'a' repeated n times?  I didn't get that from the question, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: @Stephen: I believe it's a common notation in language theory. The question I linked to uses the same notation. I've modified my answer to use traditional regex notation.