# Is Java RegEx case-insensitive?

Tags: java, regex, case-sensitive

In Java, when doing a replaceAll to look for a regex pattern like:

```
replaceAll("\\?i\\b(\\w+)\\b(\\s+\\1)+\\b", "$1");
```

(to remove duplicate consecutive case-insensitive words, e.g. Test test), I'm not sure where I put the `?i`.  I read that it is supposed to be at the beginning, but if I take it out then i catch duplicate consecutive words (e.g. test test), but not case-insensitive words (e.g. Test test).  So I thought I could add the ?i in the beginning but that does not seem to get the job done.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/55980176/3593084

Answer (score 158, accepted):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is telling me if you want to include it at the beginning, this is the correct syntax:

```
"(?i)\\b(\\w+)\\b(\\s+\\1)+\\b"
```

Answer (score 205):

You can also match case insensitive regexs and make it more readable by using the Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE constant like:

```
Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile(MYREGEX, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mymatcher= mypattern.matcher(mystring);
```

Comment: This is much more readable than this `(?i)` thing, Java regexes were already quite unreadable :S

Comment: As a one-liner:
`boolean isMatch = Pattern.compile(myRegexString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(myString).matches();`

One could even get rid of the `Pattern.` prefix entirely with `import static`:

Answer (score 145):

Yes, case insensitivity can be enabled and disabled at will in Java regex.

It looks like you want something like this:

```
    System.out.println(
        "Have a meRry MErrY Christmas ho Ho hO"
            .replaceAll("(?i)\\b(\\w+)(\\s+\\1)+\\b", "$1")
    );
    // Have a meRry Christmas ho
```

Note that the *embedded* [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag is `(?i)` not `\?i`. Note also that one superfluous `\b` has been removed from the pattern.

The `(?i)` is placed at the beginning of the pattern to enable case-insensitivity. In this particular case, it is not overridden later in the pattern, so in effect the whole pattern is case-insensitive.

It is worth noting that in fact you can limit case-insensitivity to only parts of the whole pattern. Thus, the question of where to put it really depends on the specification (although for this particular problem it doesn't matter since `\w` is case-insensitive.

To demonstrate, here's a similar example of collapsing runs of letters like `"AaAaaA"` to just `"A"`.

```
    System.out.println(
        "AaAaaA eeEeeE IiiIi OoooOo uuUuUuu"
            .replaceAll("(?i)\\b([A-Z])\\1+\\b", "$1")
    ); // A e I O u
```

Now suppose that we specify that the run should only be collapsed only if it starts with an uppercase letter. Then we must put the `(?i)` in the appropriate place:

```
    System.out.println(
        "AaAaaA eeEeeE IiiIi OoooOo uuUuUuu"
            .replaceAll("\\b([A-Z])(?i)\\1+\\b", "$1")
    ); // A eeEeeE I O uuUuUuu
```

More generally, you can enable and disable any flag within the pattern as you wish.

#### See also

- [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [regular-expressions.info/Modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

  - *Specifying Modes Inside The Regular Expression*

    - Instead of `/regex/i` (`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` in Java), you can do `/(?i)regex/`
  - *Turning Modes On and Off for Only Part of The Regular Expression*

    - You can also do `/first(?i)second(?-i)third/`
  - *Modifier Spans*

    - You can also do `/first(?i:second)third/`
- [regular-expressions.info/Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (there's always a `\b` between a `\w` and a `\s`)

#### Related questions

- [Can you make just part of a regex case-insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632/can-you-make-just-part-of-a-regex-case-insensitive)
- [Case sensitive and insensitive in the same pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117159/case-sensitive-and-insensitive-in-the-same-pattern)

Answer (score 46):

If your whole expression is case insensitive, you can just specify the [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag:

```
Pattern.compile(regexp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is exactily I was looking for. In python we have re.IGNORECASE was looking for similar answer in JAVA.

Comment: Bit it will not work with some Cyrillic symbols and German Umlauts.

Answer (score 1):

You also can lead your initial string, which you are going to check for pattern matching, to lower case. And use in your pattern lower case symbols respectively.