# How to modify this regular expression to be case insensitive while searching for curse words?

Tags: java, regex

At the moment, this profanity filter finds `darn` and `golly` but not `Darn` or `Golly` or `DARN` or `GOLLY`.

```
List<String> bannedWords = Arrays.asList("darn", "golly", "gosh");

StringBuilder re = new StringBuilder();
for (String bannedWord : bannedWords)
{
    if (re.length() > 0)
        re.append("|");
    String quotedWord = Pattern.quote(bannedWord);
    re.append(quotedWord);
}

inputString = inputString.replaceAll(re.toString(), "[No cursing please!]");
```

How can it be modified to be case insensitive?

Comment: RegEx isn't the most efficient way to find a substring occurrence.  If performance matters in this case, there are a number of more efficient substring matching algorithms http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: You probably also want to learn about `\b` to avoid making another clbuttic mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a precompiled java.util.regex.Pattern

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re.toString(),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);//do this only once

inputString = p.matcher(inputString).replaceAll("[No cursing please!]");
```

Answer (score 3):

Start the expression with `(?i)`.

I.e., change `re.toString()` to `"(?i)" + re.toString()`.

From the [documentation of `Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> `(?idmsux-idmsux)`    Nothing, but turns match flags `i d m s u x` on - off

where `i` is the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag.

Comment: Teaching aix something... that should be a silver or gold badge ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag, or simply add `(?i)` to the beginning of your regex.

```
StringBuilder re = new StringBuilder("(?i)");
```

You'll also need to change your conditional to

```
if (re.length() > 4)
```

Setting the flag via @ratchetFreak's answer is probably best, however.  It allows for your condition to stay the same (which is more intuitive) and gives you a clear idea of what's going on in the code.

For more info, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436118/is-java-regex-case-insensitive) and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436118/is-java-regex-case-insensitive/3439064#3439064) which gives some decent explanation into using regex's in java.

Comment: Beware of the `if (re.length() > 0)` condition.