# Regular expression (three types of a word)?

Tags: java, regex, match

I am new to regular expressions and need some help.

I have these sentences:

```
this is a-word
a word this is
aword is this
AWord is this
A-WORD is this
```

I'd like to know if the word `a word` or `a-word` or `aword` or `AWord` or `A-WORD` is in the sentence.

I tried this:

```
String sentence = "AWord is this";
String regex = "(a(\\s,'-','')word)\\i";
if (sentence.matches( regex)){
  .....
}
```

Comment: \\i doesn't work this way in Java - you need to use Pattern.compile with CASE_INSENSITIVE flag http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
a[^\w]?word
```

This will match any `a` followed by anything but a char, followed by `word`.

To match a narrower range of strings use  [-\s]

Put `(?i)` at the beginning of the regex to make it case insensitive

```
(?i)a[^\w]?word
```

([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436118/is-java-regex-case-insensitive), search here for other ways to search strings in a case insensitive way)

and remember to escape the `\` to `\\`

The "safest" way is however to use this one

```
((a word)|(a-word)|(aword)|(AWord)|(A-WORD))
```

because it will match exactly what you need (if you know the exact domain of what you are looking for)

Comment: Must also be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `(?:a[ -]?word|A-?W(?:ord|ORD))`
It will match all words you listed