# Java case-insensitive match

Tags: java, regex

How to match in a case-insensetive way in Java? I mean I want to write a regex like `.*unknow.*user.*`. But I wanna match `unknow user` as well as `UnKnow UsER` and so forth. What is the easiest way to do that in Java?

Comment: You can also add `(?i)` at the beginning, as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436118/is-java-regex-case-insensitive

Comment: or write like `[uU][nN]...`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Pattern`, you can do it like this `Pattern p =  Pattern.compile("YOUR_REGEX", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Check out [this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/case_insensitive_matching_in_java) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case insensitive flag:

```
(?i).*unknow.*user.*
```