# Regex with allowing missing characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to a find a way to determine whether a string contains at least n number of character in a specific order.

I am processing an enormous amount of data written by hand and the amount of typos is pretty crazy.

I need to find text parts in a large string looking something like:

> irrelevant text MONKEY, CHIMP: more irrelevant text

I need to find   **MONKEY, CHIMP:**

The ways this is mistyped is pretty crazy. Here is an extra weird example:

> MonKEY  , CHIMp  :

I've got to a point in my regex where I'm able to find all of these occurances. Probably not the nicest solution, but here it is:

```
 (m|M)(o|O)(n|N)(k|K)(e|E)(y|Y),?\s+(c|C)(h|H)(i|I)(m|M)(p|P)(\s+)?:
```

Looks a bit weird but it works.

Unfortunately the weirdness does not stop here. I need to amend this regex so that it also allows for 1 missing letter in each word.

So I would need to amend this regex so it would also work for something like:

> MonKEY  , CIMp  :
>
> onKEY  , ChIMp  :
>
> onKEY  , CIMp  :

I would think that there should be a way to tell the regex that it should require wordlength-1 exact number of characters to match.

Is there a simple way to do this?

I'm been looking into {4, } but I'm not sure this is the right direction or if it could be applied here.

Thank in advance,
Peter

Comment: You can make the Regex a lot easier if you normalize the text by putting it to lower case for example.

Comment: Or by doing a case insensitive match. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436118/is-java-regex-case-insensitive

Comment: Regex alone might not be enough for a scalable solution. You might end up needing your own parser evaluating similarities with a dictionary word, e.g. with a Levenshtein distance metric.

Comment: Have you considered using a more advanced algorithm than regex? E.g. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/jacoco/org.apache.commons.text.similarity/LevenshteinDistance.java.html

Comment: This is horrible for Regex (it just gets way too long). You should probably use [Fuzzy text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327513/fuzzy-string-search-library-in-java) instead.

Answer (score 2):

With pure regex, then best you could do is something like (whitespace added for readability):

```
/
  ^
  (
    monkey\s*,?\s*chimp\s*:
  |
    onkey\s*,?\s*chimp\s*:
  |
    mnkey\s*,?\s*chimp\s*:
  |
    ...
  )
  $
/ix
```

However, this is a very long-winded approach and still won't account for all sorts of other fuzzy-matches like `"Monkey, Chinp:"` or `"Monkey; Chimp:"`.

---

An alternative approach you could take is to *first* check the length of the string:

```
/^\w{10,15}$/
```

and *then* perform some very-fuzzy match on it:

```
/m?o?n?k?e?y?\s*,?\s*c?h?i?m?p?\s*:/i
```

However, you'd need to be careful here since there may be some bizarre results included in the match list, such as:

```
"mon      c:"
```

---

I would recommend taking a different, non-regex approach of utilising a [Levenshtein Distance](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/jacoco/org.apache.commons.text.similarity/LevenshteinDistance.java.html) library. This will allow you to set generic boundaries on "*how closely* the string needs to match `Monkey, Chimp`"

Answer (score 0):

^\w{10,10}$ # allows words of exactly 10 characters. Set it to length - 1.
Then make each of the characters optional.

I think just {10} works as well.

Comment: You can just write `\w{10}`; there's no need to suggest `\w{10,10}`. However, this does not answer OP's problem: They wanted a pattern that would also match, for example, `"MonKEY , CIMp"` - which is **13** characters.

Comment: Thats why I wrote, that then each character should be made optional. So that it can be left out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this, this is not very beautiful but your example is strange too

First use case insensitive :(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE)

I don't know solution in one treatment but you can first check for `"m?o?n?k?e?y?\s+,?\s+c?h?i?m?p?(\s+)?:"` and then for length in another test, this will be easy

Comment: So things as fuzzy as  `mon         ,        p`will match? Doesn't sound very reliable to me...

Comment: @TomLord First thanks for this so constructive and useful comment. Then I as wrote you might add also a test for length, and other ones if needed, I just add the structure which the order and the possibility to have letter less, if you have better idea just click on the blue button down called "Post your answer"

Comment: StackOverflow has truncated my comment, so perhaps you misunderstood due to the formatting. There are meant to be **several** spaces on either side of the comma - so the length check will still pass. You can also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44783986/1954610) below.