# Regular expressions in java with a variable

Tags: java, regex, variables

I have a variable *v* that possibly appears more than one time consecutively in a string. I want to make it so that all consecutive *v*s turn into just one *v*. For example:

```
String s = "Hello, world!";
String v = "l";
```

The regex would turn "Hello, world!" into "Helo, world!"

So I want to do something like

```
s = s.replaceAll(vv+, v)
```

But obviously that won't work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concatenate the two "v" Strings.

Try `s = s.replaceAll(v + v + "+", v)`

Comment: This will only work for characters that aren't special characters in a regex context.

Answer (score 17):

Let's iteratively develop the solution; in each step we point out what the problems are and fix it until we arrive at the final answer.

We can start with something like this:

```
String s = "What???? Impo$$ible!!!";
String v = "!";

s = s.replaceAll(v + "{2,}", v);
System.out.println(s);
// "What???? Impo$$ible!"
```

`{2,}` is the regex syntax for finite repetition, meaning "at least 2 of" in this case.

It just so happen that the above works because `!` is not a regex metacharacter. Let's see what happens if we try the following:

```
String v = "?";

s = s.replaceAll(v + "{2,}", v);
// Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:       
// Dangling meta character '?'
```

One way to fix the problem is to use `Pattern.quote` so that `v` is taken literally:

```
s = s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(v) + "{2,}", v);
System.out.println(s);
// "What? Impo$$ible!!!"
```

It turns out that this isn't the only thing we need to worry about: in replacement strings, `\` and `$` are also special metacharacters. That explains why we get the following problem:

```
String v = "$";
s = s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(v) + "{2,}", v);
// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
// String index out of range: 1
```

Since we want `v` to be taken literally as a replacement string, we use `Matcher.quoteReplacement` as follows:

```
s = s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(v) + "{2,}", Matcher.quoteReplacement(v));
System.out.println(s);
// "What???? Impo$ible!!!"
```

Lastly, repetition has higher precedence than concatenation. This means the following:

```
System.out.println(  "hahaha".matches("ha{3}")    ); // false
System.out.println(  "haaa".matches("ha{3}")      ); // true
System.out.println(  "hahaha".matches("(ha){3}")  ); // true
```

So if `v` can contain multiple characters, you'd want to group it before applying the repetition. You can use a non-capturing group in this case, since you don't need to create a backreference.

```
String s = "well, well, well, look who's here...";
String v = "well, ";
s = s.replaceAll("(?:" +Pattern.quote(v)+ "){2,}", Matcher.quoteReplacement(v));
System.out.println(s);
// "well, look who's here..."
```

#### Summary

- To match an arbitrary literal string that may contain regex metacharacters, use [`Pattern.quote`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- To replace with an arbitrary literal string that may contain replacement metacharacters, use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29)

#### References

- [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)
- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Finite Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

---

#### Bonus material

The following example uses reluctant repetition, capturing group and backreferences mixed with case-insensitive matching:

```
    System.out.println(
        "omgomgOMGOMG???? Yes we can! YES WE CAN! GOAAALLLL!!!!"
            .replaceAll("(?i)(.+?)\\1+", "$1")
    );
    // "omg? Yes we can! GOAL!"
```

#### Related questions

- [Regex to match tags like `<A>`, `<BB>`, `<CCC>` but not `<ABC>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110300/regex-to-match-tags-like-a-bb-ccc-but-not-abc/)

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Brackets for Grouping and Backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: This is a way better solution, even down to the `"{2,}"` being better regex form than concatenating.  Both aren't functionally necessary since just a `Pattern.quote(v) + "+"` would work (a single match being replaced with itself results in no change).

Comment: don't you need to add noncapturing parentheses e.g. "(?:"+Pattern.quote(v)+"){2,}" for multiple characters in the string? (as per my answer and gustafc's)

Answer (score 5):

Use `x{2,}` to match `x` at least twice.

To be able to replace characters with special meanings for regexps, you'd use [`Pattern.quote`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String part = Pattern.quote(v);
s = s.replaceAll(part + "{2,}", v);
```

To replace things longer than one character, use non-capturing groups:

```
String part = "(?:" + Pattern.quote(v) + ")";
s = s.replaceAll(part + "{2,}", v);
```

Comment: +1; I incorporated the need for grouping into my answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

With regex's in Java make sure to use [Pattern.quote](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) and [Matcher.quoteReplacement](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29):

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex2 {
    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "Hello, world!";
        String v = "l";

        System.out.println(doit(s,v));

        s = "Test: ??r??r Solo ??r Frankenstein!";
        v = "??r";

        System.out.println(doit(s,v));

    }

    private static String doit(String s, String v) 
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:"+Pattern.quote(v)+"){2,}");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find())
        {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(v));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't wait until `Matcher` takes any `Appendable` instead of `StringBuffer`... It's an RFE somewhere in the bugdb...

Comment: agreed. (would much rather use StringBuilder)

Answer (score 2):

```
s = s.replaceAll (v + "+", v)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but this will only work for characters that aren't special characters in a regex context.